# Mesh gets out of sync while in edit-mode (Python)

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

When modifying/accessing a mesh in Python, changes made while in edit-mode by the user are not available to Python.

```
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[x].select
```

For example, doesn't change for any vertex  until I (for example) switch from edit to object mode.

Is there a way a way to access the current state of the mesh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In edit-mode, the mesh as defined by `bpy.types.Mesh` is not used, there is in fact a different mesh-representation being used (`bmesh.types.BMesh`), which supports editing operations and modifications.

So changes to `bpy.context.object.data` are not displayed, and they will be overwritten when exiting editmode.

Instead, you have to access the BMesh.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
```

Once you have a bmesh from the edit-mesh, you are directly accessing the same data which the user is manipulating.

For the full example, see:

> Text Editor -> Templates -> Python -> BMesh Simple Editmode

See BMesh API docs:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html