# How to move the points of a Curve in Python while in Edit Mode

Tags: python

I built a script that creates a bunch of curves. So far so good. Each curve (3d curve) is placed correctly a z=0 but the points of the curve are not at z=0. So I need to write a script that will put every point of the curve at z=0

I came up with this simple script after having select a curve :

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
for p in bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.bezier_points:
    p.co.z = 0
```

But nothing happens, no crash but the point remain at their original Z

Thanks for the help

Comment: This should work if your curve is a bezier curve. Check the `bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.type`. Could be any of these: `('POLY', 'BEZIER', 'BSPLINE', 'CARDINAL', 'NURBS')`

Comment: @Gaeldk, you can't modify Curve geometry / points that way directly with python while the object is in Edit Mode. Think of _edit mode_ being for user interaction with the UI. -- place the object in Object mode and then update the points with Python.

Comment: I hesitate to answer because it seems the answer has been given in several answers to slightly different but ultimately similar questions already present on BSE. -- but this is a fair question each time.

Answer (score 3):

`bpy.data.Curves` don't currently have a secondary representation, like `bpy.data.Mesh` does. Meshes can be represented as a `bmesh`, and they *can* be manipulated by Python while the Mesh is in Edit Mode. Curves on the other hand (Spline, Bezier, NURBS) don't have an additional representation that lets you modify their data via script while in Edit Mode.

A solution is to switch the Edit Mode to Object Mode, then do your manipulation, then switch back to Edit Mode if you need.

in short

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
for p in bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.bezier_points:
    p.co.z = 0
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

You won't notice it switching in and out of OBJECT mode, but the `bezier_points` will be updated, and it will be placed back in EDIT mode.

[Ideasman42 states](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20887/mesh-gets-out-of-sync-while-in-edit-mode-python/20888#20888): *"changes to bpy.context.object.data are not displayed, and they will be overwritten when exiting editmode."*